# Computer freezing when I try to add an attachement to an e-mail

Tags: 10.04

my computer froze when trying to attach file to e-mail and when I restarted my computer a black screen came up display this with different numbers in front of it each time it was repeated multiple times.

"Buffer 1/0 error on device sr0 logical block 0"
"end_request: 1/0 error sector 0"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a hard disk about to fail (or has already done so). If you have a LiveCD or USB you can boot to that and try repairing the filesystem or at least get your data off the drive.

See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD